# Generate an Int random number to Label By Click Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, random, digit

I need to generate a random int by clicking a `UIButton` and make a `UIlabel` print the result.

And how do I use randoms in an array? For example, I want to generate a 4 digit number in one single label by clicking the button. After that I want the user to enter the generated numbers into a text field to confirm the mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you get random max 4 digit number:

```
var number = arc4random_uniform(9999)
```

And if you have label, just assign the value to your label:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func randomNumber(sender: AnyObject) {
    myLabel.text = String(arc4random_uniform(9999))
}
```

And for array:

```
var myArray = [Int]()

for index in 0..<100 {
    var number = arc4random_uniform(9999)
    myArray.append(Int(number))
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by confirming it, can you be more precisely?

Comment: this 'label.integerValue = arc4random_uniform(9999)' told me that UILabel doesn't have a member named 'integerValue' ??

Comment: So you use iOS app, use:

"label.text = String(arc4random_uniform(9999))"

Comment: So you mean i can't pool the lable text and covert it to an int because the random method want it int , Right ? So i have to explain to Xcode that rather that its a random int , the label should take it as a string , is that right ?

Comment: I dont know much iOS, but i assume that UILabel's value must be a string. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: thank you very much man for the answer , BUT i have an error for the array look : number.append(Int(number)) told me UInt32 does not have a member named 'append'

Comment: Check my answer again, "myArray.append(Int(number))"

Comment: var number = (arc4random_uniform(8999)%9999 )+1000 will generate 4 digit random numbers from 1000 to 9999